# Determining and setting host target triple and instruction extensions in LLVM-C API

Tags: llvm

The following lengthy C program generates a simple LLVM module containing a function that merely calls `llvm.x86.sse41.round.ps`. It emits the bitcode file and then runs the code generated by LLVM. My question is how do I find out target triple and instruction extensions like SSE or AVX of the host machine and how do I add this information to the LLVM module or how do I otherwise tell it to the LLVM execution engine. Here is, what I do:

```
$ cat ctest/avx-instruction-selection.c
#include <llvm-c/Core.h>
#include <llvm-c/Target.h>
#include <llvm-c/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm-c/BitWriter.h>
#include <llvm-c/Transforms/Scalar.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#if 1
const int vectorSize = 4;
const char* roundName = "llvm.x86.sse41.round.ps";
#else
const int vectorSize = 8;
const char* roundName = "llvm.x86.avx.round.ps.256";
#endif

int main ()
{
  LLVMModuleRef module;
  LLVMExecutionEngineRef execEngine;
  LLVMTargetDataRef targetData;
  LLVMTypeRef floatType, vectorType, ptrType, voidType, funcType, roundType, int32Type;
  LLVMValueRef func, roundFunc;
  LLVMValueRef param, loaded, const1, callRound;
  LLVMBuilderRef builder;
  LLVMBasicBlockRef block;
  const int false = 0;

  LLVMInitializeX86TargetInfo();
  LLVMInitializeX86Target();
  LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC();
  module = LLVMModuleCreateWithName("_module");
  LLVMSetTarget(module, "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu");
  floatType = LLVMFloatType();
  vectorType = LLVMVectorType(floatType, vectorSize);
  ptrType = LLVMPointerType(vectorType, 0);
  voidType = LLVMVoidType();
  LLVMTypeRef roundParams[] = { ptrType };
  roundType = LLVMFunctionType(voidType, roundParams, 1, false);
  func = LLVMAddFunction(module, "round", roundType);
  LLVMSetLinkage(func, LLVMExternalLinkage);
  builder = LLVMCreateBuilder();
  block = LLVMAppendBasicBlock(func, "_L1");
  LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, block);
  param = LLVMGetParam(func, 0);
  loaded = LLVMBuildLoad(builder, param, "");
  int32Type = LLVMIntType(32);
  LLVMTypeRef funcParams[] = { vectorType, int32Type } ;
  funcType = LLVMFunctionType(vectorType, funcParams, 2, false);
  roundFunc = LLVMAddFunction(module, roundName, funcType);
  LLVMSetLinkage(roundFunc, LLVMExternalLinkage);
  const1 = LLVMConstInt(int32Type, 1, false);
  LLVMValueRef callParams [] = { loaded, const1 } ;
  callRound = LLVMBuildCall(builder, roundFunc, callParams, 2, "");
  LLVMSetInstructionCallConv(callRound, 0);
  LLVMAddInstrAttribute(callRound, 0, 0);
  LLVMBuildStore(builder, callRound, param);
  LLVMBuildRetVoid(builder);
  LLVMWriteBitcodeToFile(module, "round-avx.bc");
  char *errorMsg;
  LLVMCreateExecutionEngineForModule(&execEngine, module, &errorMsg);
  targetData = LLVMGetExecutionEngineTargetData(execEngine);
  size_t vectorSize0 = LLVMStoreSizeOfType(targetData, vectorType);
  size_t vectorAlign = LLVMABIAlignmentOfType(targetData, vectorType);
  float vector[vectorSize];
  printf("%lx, size %lx, align %lx\n", (size_t)vector, vectorSize0, vectorAlign);
  LLVMGenericValueRef genericVector = LLVMCreateGenericValueOfPointer(vector);
  LLVMGenericValueRef runParams[] = { genericVector } ;
  LLVMRunFunction(execEngine, func, 1, runParams);
  return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall -o ctest/avx-instruction-selection ctest/avx-instruction-selection.c `/usr/lib/llvm-3.4/bin/llvm-config --cflags --ldflags` -lLLVM-3.4

$ ctest/avx-instruction-selection
7fff590431c0, size 10, align 10

$ ls round-avx.bc
round-avx.bc

$ llvm-dis -o - round-avx.bc
; ModuleID = 'round-avx.bc'
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

define void @round(<4 x float>*) {
_L1:
  %1 = load <4 x float>* %0
  %2 = call <4 x float> @llvm.x86.sse41.round.ps(<4 x float> %1, i32 1)
  store <4 x float> %2, <4 x float>* %0
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone
declare <4 x float> @llvm.x86.sse41.round.ps(<4 x float>, i32) #0

attributes #0 = { nounwind readnone }

$ gcc -Wall -o ctest/avx-instruction-selection ctest/avx-instruction-selection.c `/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/llvm-config --cflags --ldflags` -lLLVM-3.5

$ ctest/avx-instruction-selection
7ffed6170350, size 10, align 10
LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: intrinsic %llvm.x86.sse41.round.ps

$ gcc -Wall -o ctest/avx-instruction-selection ctest/avx-instruction-selection.c `/usr/lib/llvm-3.6/bin/llvm-config --cflags --ldflags` -lLLVM-3.6

$ ctest/avx-instruction-selection
7ffeae91eb40, size 10, align 10
LLVM ERROR: Target does not support MC emission!

$ gcc -Wall -o ctest/avx-instruction-selection ctest/avx-instruction-selection.c `/usr/lib/llvm-3.7/bin/llvm-config --cflags --ldflags` -lLLVM-3.7

$ ctest/avx-instruction-selection
7fffb6464ea0, size 10, align 10
LLVM ERROR: Target does not support MC emission!

$ gcc -Wall -o ctest/avx-instruction-selection ctest/avx-instruction-selection.c `/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/llvm-config --cflags --ldflags` -lLLVM-3.8

$ ctest/avx-instruction-selection
7ffd5e233000, size 10, align 10
LLVM ERROR: Target does not support MC emission!
```

Summarized: With LLVM-3.4 the example works, with LLVM-3.5 the intrinsic function `round.ps` cannot be found and LLVM-3.6 and later say something about MC emissions that I do not understand.

As I understand, LLVM-3.5 does not find the `round.ps` intrinsic and I guess that it cannot find it because I have not told it about the existing SSE extension. When running `llc` I can add the option `-mattr=sse4.1` but how can I tell it to the execution engine?

Second question: How can I find out about the available instruction extensions like SSE of the host machine via the LLVM-C API? On x86 I can call the CPUID instruction but is there a way that works uniformly on all platforms and can LLVM assist detection of extensions?

Third question: I have hard-coded the target triple into the C code. How can I find out the host target-triple via the LLVM-C API?

Last question: What about this MC emission error?

Comment: I see that `llvm-config --host-target` emits the content of LLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE. There are llvm/Config/config.h and llvm/Config/llvm-config.h files containing the macros LLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE and LLVM_HOST_TRIPLE. They are not strictly part of the LLVM-C API but are plain C.

Comment: If remove LLVMInitializeX86TargetInfo(), LLVMInitializeX86Target() or both, then the "MC emission" error disappears and I get consistently "Cannot select: intrinsic %llvm.x86.sse41.round.ps" on all tested LLVM versions.

Comment: In "llvm/Support/Host.h" I found the function `getHostCPUName`. This should answer the question about available instruction extensions on the host machine.

Comment: In "lib/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngineBindings.cpp" there is the definition of `LLVMCreateExecutionEngineForModule`. I copied this function to my code and added `.setMCPU("corei7-avx")` to the `builder`. However, the runtime error "Cannot select: intrinsic %llvm.x86.sse41.round.ps" remains.

Comment: I checked how `lli` works and found that it additionally calls   `LLVMInitializeNativeAsmPrinter();` and `LLVMInitializeNativeAsmParser();`.
The initializations `LLVMInitializeX86TargetInfo()` and `LLVMInitializeX86Target()` must remain, but the three X86Target initializations can be replaced by a single `LLVMInitializeNativeTarget()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying around a lot I think the answer is as follows:

Replace the lines

```
LLVMInitializeX86TargetInfo();
LLVMInitializeX86Target();
LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC();
```

by

```
LLVMInitializeNativeTarget();
LLVMInitializeNativeAsmPrinter();
LLVMInitializeNativeAsmParser();
```

Replace the call of `LLVMCreateExecutionEngineForModule` by a call to the custom function `LLVMCreateExecutionEngineForModuleCPU`. It is the original implementation of `LLVMCreateExecutionEngineForModule` plus a call of `setMCPU`.

```
#define LLVM_VERSION (LLVM_VERSION_MAJOR * 100 + LLVM_VERSION_MINOR)

LLVMBool LLVMCreateExecutionEngineForModuleCPU
    (LLVMExecutionEngineRef *OutEE,
     LLVMModuleRef M,
     char **OutError) {
  std::string Error;
#if LLVM_VERSION < 306
  EngineBuilder builder(unwrap(M));
#else
  EngineBuilder builder(std::unique_ptr<Module>(unwrap(M)));
#endif
  builder.setEngineKind(EngineKind::Either)
         .setMCPU(sys::getHostCPUName().data())
         .setErrorStr(&Error);
  if (ExecutionEngine *EE = builder.create()){
    *OutEE = wrap(EE);
    return 0;
  }
  *OutError = strdup(Error.c_str());
  return 1;
}
```

I should also add

```
float vector[vectorSize] __attribute__((aligned(32)));
```

in order to align the array for AVX vectors.

According to an answer in the thread [crash JIT with AVX intrinsics](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-August/103598.html) `LLVMRunFunction` is restricted to `main`-like prototypes (apparently only in MCJIT). Thus we should also replace the `LLVMRunFunction` stuff by

```
void (*funcPtr) (float *);
funcPtr = LLVMGetPointerToGlobal(execEngine, func);
funcPtr(vector);
```

Comment: error: ‘LLVMCreateExecutionEngineForModuleCPU’ was not declared in this scope