# LLVM ERROR: MCJIT::runFunction does not support full-featured argument passing

Tags: c++, c, llvm

I have got an example from [here](https://github.com/paulsmith/getting-started-llvm-c-api/blob/master/sum.c) and I faced with a run error

> LLVM ERROR: Target does not support MC emission!

which I fixed it by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738123/determining-and-setting-host-target-triple-and-instruction-extensions-in-llvm-c).

nevertheless, I still observe runtime problem:

```
 ./example 3 5
```

> LLVM ERROR: MCJIT::runFunction does not support full-featured argument passing. Please use ExecutionEngine::getFunctionAddress and cast the result to the desired function pointer type.

main.cpp

```
/**
 * LLVM equivalent of:
 *
 * int sum(int a, int b) {
 *     return a + b;
 * }
 */

#include <llvm-c/Core.h>
#include <llvm-c/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm-c/Target.h>
#include <llvm-c/Analysis.h>
#include <llvm-c/BitWriter.h>

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    LLVMModuleRef mod = LLVMModuleCreateWithName("my_module");

    LLVMTypeRef param_types[] = { LLVMInt32Type(), LLVMInt32Type() };
    LLVMTypeRef ret_type = LLVMFunctionType(LLVMInt32Type(), param_types, 2, 0);
    LLVMValueRef sum = LLVMAddFunction(mod, "sum", ret_type);

    LLVMBasicBlockRef entry = LLVMAppendBasicBlock(sum, "entry");

    LLVMBuilderRef builder = LLVMCreateBuilder();
    LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, entry);
    LLVMValueRef tmp = LLVMBuildAdd(builder, LLVMGetParam(sum, 0), LLVMGetParam(sum, 1), "tmp");
    LLVMBuildRet(builder, tmp);

    char *error = NULL;
    LLVMVerifyModule(mod, LLVMAbortProcessAction, &error);
    LLVMDisposeMessage(error);

    LLVMExecutionEngineRef engine;
    error = NULL;
    LLVMLinkInMCJIT();
    LLVMInitializeNativeTarget();
    LLVMInitializeNativeAsmPrinter(); // added
    LLVMInitializeNativeAsmParser();  // added
    if (LLVMCreateExecutionEngineForModule(&engine, mod, &error) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create execution engine\n");
        abort();
    }
    if (error)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", error);
        LLVMDisposeMessage(error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s x y\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    long long x = strtoll(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    long long y = strtoll(argv[2], NULL, 10);

    LLVMGenericValueRef args[] = {
        LLVMCreateGenericValueOfInt(LLVMInt32Type(), x, 0),
        LLVMCreateGenericValueOfInt(LLVMInt32Type(), y, 0)
    };
    LLVMGenericValueRef res = LLVMRunFunction(engine, sum, 2, args);
    printf("%d\n", (int)LLVMGenericValueToInt(res, 0));

    // Write out bitcode to file
    if (LLVMWriteBitcodeToFile(mod, "sum.bc") != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error writing bitcode to file, skipping\n");
    }

    LLVMDisposeBuilder(builder);
    LLVMDisposeExecutionEngine(engine);
}
```

Though the meessage is clear for the view point of the code author, for me as a user it is so cryptic. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you using the C API when, according to your file extension, you're programming in C++? Or alternatively: why did you name the file `.cpp` if it's C code?

Comment: @sepp2k, because the example is in c. I like to write C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [`MCJIT::runFunction`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1MCJIT.html#a0198943262fb715d77dfd24ef32f9399):

> For MCJIT execution engines, clients are encouraged to use the "GetFunctionAddress" method (rather than runFunction) and cast the returned uint64_t to the desired function pointer type. However, for backwards compatibility MCJIT's implementation can execute 'main-like' function (i.e. those returning void or int, and taking either no arguments or (int, char*[])).

So you can't call `MCJIT::runFunction` (and by extension the C API's `LLVMRunFunction` when used with an MCJIT engine) unless the arguments array is either empty or consists of only an `i32` and an `i8*` (in that order). Your array contains two `i32`s, so it does not meet those restrictions.

As stated in the documentation (and the exception message), you should instead use `ExecutionEngine::getFunctionAddress` (or its C wrapper `LLVMGetFunctionAddress`), cast the result to `int (*)(int, int)` and then call it as `f(0, 0);`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible: `error: ‘getFunctionAddress’ was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: @ar2015 It's referring to the `getFunctionAddress` method of the `ExecutionEngine` class. When using the C API, you should be using the corresponding C wrapper.

Comment: I start feeling this example is a wrong example for me. Is LLVM for C and C++ significantly different?

Comment: @ar2015 The main difference is that in the C++ API you have namespaces and classes, calling methods on objects created from classes from the `llvm` namespace, whereas in C everything's free functions with name spacing done through the names because that's what's available in C. It's certainly possible to translate from one API to the other if you're somewhat familiar with the C++ API, but certainly if you're programming in C++, sticking with examples for the C++ API will be less confusing. Another problem in this particular case is that you example you found is quite old/outdated.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you don't mind, would you please let me know if llvm C++ api allows local variables or based on SSA, this is duty of language to turn everything to SSA and avoid local variables?

Comment: @ar2015 That's not really a property of the API. That is, LLVM has the same restrictions regardless of which API you use or whether you're writing LLVM assembly to a file and invoking `llc` or `clang` on it without using an API at all. Either way, registers in LLVM are SSA and to implement mutable local variables you can use `alloca`. It is perfectly possible and common to generate code that uses `alloca` for all local variables and then let LLVM's mem2reg pass replace the variables with registers where possible. That way you don't have to deal with SSA yourself.